# React Redirect not working after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

So I have a login page, and on logging in, I want the user to be redirected to the home page. I have it set up so that the state (redirectTo) is changed to true. This logs correctly.

However, in my render method, I have an if statement where:

```
render() { 

if (this.state.redirectTo) {
        return (<Redirect to="/" />);
    } else {
        return ( ///rest of render here
```

Here is the logic:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        redirectTo: false
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
}


  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        redirectTo: false
    });
   }
    handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('handleSubmit');

    axios
        .post('/user/login', {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('login response: ');
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 200) {
                // update App.js state
                this.setState({
                    redirectTo: true
                });
                this.props.updateUser({
                    loggedIn: true,
                    username: response.data.username,
                    id: response.data.id
                });
                // update the state to redirect to home
            }

            console.log(this.state.redirectTo);             
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(this.state);
            console.log('login error: ');
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

I've looked at a lot of other topics and I seem to be doing it correctly.

When logged in => change state to true => if state = true => redirect to '/' within the render

any tips on what i'm doing wrong? The state is in fact changing, and after log-in, I'm sent to a blank page. this happens regardless of if the state is changed. I feel like I'm pretty close but have been stumped for some time

Comment: Is this the `RedirectTo` component you shared under _here is the logic_ line ? And I don't see any redirection in terms of url manipulation, how exactly routing happens here ?

Comment: @dashboard sorry I wasn't clear. Within the .then of the axios call is where I changed the state of redirectTo = true.

later when the page renders, my if/else statement determines what shows.

I thought that was enough for it to redirect, but since the page is already rendered, and the state changes afterwards, I guess it's not and I'm missing something?

Comment: Are you using react router?

Comment: No he doesn't. He's selectively rendering two different views by the `redirectTo` field in state.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using react router method without using if/else statement.

on your .then on last line after you've done all things do

```
this.props.history.push('/');
```

you need to import withRouter with

```
import {  withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and export your component with withRouter (withRouter is a higher order component)
https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

```
export default withRouter(YourComponent)
```

also remember you should have anywhere on your code the url '/' attached to any component you want to render

Comment: i tried it but no dice. could it have to do with axios?

Comment: I don't think so, are you getting any error message?

Comment: scratch that. So i'm getting :'Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `responsive`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: responsive="true" or responsive={value.toString()}.'

but that's in my index.js so idk

Comment: I think we need more code to know where the error come from